# Validating user input as numeric, then as a whole number using Tryparse

Tags: c#

I have to create a program that validates user input by checking if the input is numeric, a whole number, and within a range. Error message must be provided for each if incorrect. I can't figure out how to validate as a number and then as a whole number and provide an error message for each separate issue(If user enters "Ten" provide message "Must be numeric" if user enters "10.1" provide message "Must be a whole number". Any recommendations?

```
        const int INPUT_MIN = 0;    
        const int INPUT_MAX = 50;   
        const int DAILY_COUNT = 7;  

        double totalVehicles = 0.0; 
        int avgDailyVehicles = 0;   
        int highestDay = 0;         
        int lowestDay = 0;          
        int dailySold = 0;          
        string userInput = "";      
        int[] salesArray = new int[DAILY_COUNT];    

        do {
            for (int dayCount = 1; dayCount <= salesArray.Length; dayCount++)
            {

                Console.Write("Please enter the number of vehicles sold on day " + dayCount + ": ");

                {

                    if (Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out dailySold))
                    {

                        if ((dailySold >= INPUT_MIN && dailySold <= INPUT_MAX))
                        {

                            salesArray[dayCount - 1] = dailySold;
                        }

                        else
                        {

                            Console.WriteLine("\n" + dailySold + " is not a valid entry. ");
                            Console.WriteLine("The amount must be between {0} and {1}. Please try again.", INPUT_MIN, INPUT_MAX);
                            dayCount--;
                        }
                    }

                    else
                    {

                        Console.WriteLine("\n" + dailySold + " is not a valid entry. ");
                        Console.WriteLine("The amount must be a whole number. Please try again.");
                        dayCount--;


                    }

                }
            }
```

Comment: could you point out, where exactly you got stuck?

Comment: I don't know where to place the Double.Tryparse for if it is numeric as well as the message that would come if it wasn't a numeric entry.

Comment: what about 10.0 ?? what it should give?

Comment: I'm assuming because it has a decimal it would not be okay.

Answer (score 0):

Use Decimal.TryParse for numeric, and Int64.TryParse for whole.

Comment: Any chance you can elaborate a little where I would put the numeric one?

Comment: I would guess make an if block around the whole parsing if block.  Enter the if if it's numeric (where you've got the whole logic), enter the else if it's not numeric.